# Multiple definition error of StringCchPrintfW when cross-compling with MinGW on Alpine linux

Tags: mingw, cross-compiling, linker-errors, alpine-linux

I'm cross-compiling opencascade on Alpine linux for windows with MinGW and run into a *multiple definition* linking error of *StringCchPrintfW*. I have managed to cross-compile and link this successfully without errors with Ubuntu linux, however I'm not sure how to debug this on Alpine, any ideas would be appreciated? The output is as follows:

```
Compiling test.exe

x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -O2 obj/geom_util.o-mingw obj/main.o-mingw
obj/util.o-mingw obj/error.o-mingw obj/geom.o-mingw obj/mesh.o-mingw
obj/shapemap.o-mingw obj/export.o-mingw obj/import.o-mingw
obj/gobj.o-mingw -L/usr/local/lib/opencascade-mingw -lTKSTEP
-lTKSTEP209 -lTKSTEPAttr -lTKSTEPBase -lTKIGES -lTKSTL -lTKXSBase
-lTKMesh -lTKOffset -lTKFillet -lTKBool -lTKBO -lTKShHealing -lTKPrim
-lTKTopAlgo -lTKGeomAlgo -lTKBRep -lTKGeomBase -lTKG3d -lTKG2d
-lTKMath -lTKernel -o test.exe -s -lws2_32 -lpsapi -static -lpthread

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingwex.a(lib64_libmingwex_a-strsafe.o):strsafe.c:(.text+0xbe3):
multiple definition of `StringCchPrintfW';
/usr/local/lib/opencascade-mingw/libTKernel.a(OSD_FileNode.cxx.o):OSD_FileNode.c:(.text$StringCchPrintfW[StringCchPrintfW]+0x0):
first defined here

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:146: test.exe] Error 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says: `StringCchPrintfW` is defined in `-lmingwex` and then redefined in `OSD_FileNode.c`.

You should check why that is and see if you can remove the definition from `OSD_FileNode.c`.

Or maybe you can get away with ignoring this using linker flag `-Wl,-allow-multiple-definition` to allow the build to continue.

Comment: `-Wl,-allow-multiple-definition` worked like a charm with i686-w64-mingw32-ld